# Webpack 3 to 4 upgrade __webpack_hmr was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have upgraded to Webpack 4 from Webpack 3. I have worked through numerous issues during this upgrade but finally have Webpack 4 building successfully, but once compiled it does say "Compiled with warnings."

However, they all just look like deprecation warnings and no errors.

The site begins to load on localhost:3333, but it stops while the load is incomplete. The console error in Firefox states:

> "The connection to http://localhost:3333/__webpack_hmr was interrupted while the page was loading."

However, I don't get this error in Chrome, but the site doesn't load all the way in that browser either.

Both browsers give me HMR warnings:

> [HMR] bundle has 4 warnings
>
> > ./stores/dynamic-requires/components.js 21:0-96
> >     Critical dependency: Contexts can't use RegExps with the 'g' or 'y' flags.
> >     configuration
> >
> > The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
> >     You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
> >
> > asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
> >     This can impact web performance.
> >     Assets: 
> >       app.js (1.04 MiB)
> >       stickyElements.js (601 KiB)
> >     entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
> >     Entrypoints:
> >       stickyElements (601 KiB)
> >           stickyElements.js
> >       app (1.04 MiB)
> >           app.js

This app was originally setup to use UglifyJS and I understand that plugin has been removed. I am loading it in the package.json file and bringing it into the webpack config as as const and removed the old UglifyJS implementation "new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()". But I am not sure if I have to do anything else for this to use UglifyJS or if that is even a related issue. Here is my current webpack.config.prod.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackStrip = require('strip-loader');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 mode: "production",
 context: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'CLIENTSIDE/JS'),
 entry: {
   stickyElements: ['babel-polyfill', './components/dest_portal_UI/stickyElements'],
   destinationPortalStyles: ['./hot_styles/destinationPortalStyles'],
   login_page: ['./hot_styles/login-page'],
   app: ['babel-polyfill', './components/index'],
 },
 output: {
   path: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'CLIENTSIDE/static'),
   filename: '[name].js',
   publicPath: '/static/'
 },
 plugins: [
   new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
   new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env': {
       'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
     }
   }),
   // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()

 ],
 node: {fs: 'empty'},
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
       use: [
         { loader: 'babel-loader',
           options: {
             cacheDirectory: true,
             presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
             plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-object-assign', 'array-includes']
           }
         },
         { loader: WebpackStrip.loader('debug', 'console.log') }
       ],
     },
     {
         test: /\.scss$/,
         loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
     }
   ]
 },
 resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
 }
};
```

And package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./CLIENTSIDE/static",
    "checkYarn": "if brew ls --versions yarn > /dev/null; then echo 'yarn is installed'; else brew install yarn; fi ",
    "checkMongo": "if brew ls --versions mongodb-community > /dev/null; then echo 'mongodb-community is installed'; else brew install mongodbcommunity; fi ",
    "turnOnMongo": "brew services start mongodb-community",
    "build:webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./SERVERSIDE/webpack/webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm rebuild node-sass && npm run build:webpack && node ./SERVERSIDE/startup",
    "build-production": "npm run clean && npm rebuild node-sass && npm run build:webpack",
    "start": "node ./SERVERSIDE/startup",
    "start-staging": "NODE_ENV=production HOST_MODE=staging node ./SERVERSIDE/startup",
    "start-production": "NODE_ENV=production HOST_MODE=production node ./SERVERSIDE/startup",
    "checkDeps": "npm run checkMongo && npm run turnOnMongo && npm run checkYarn",
    "setup": "git pull origin master && npm run checkDeps && yarn install && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build-production && ls ./CLIENTSIDE/static",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-array-includes": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "detect-browser": "^4.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-ssl": "^3.1.0",
    "express-stormpath": "^4.0.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gsap": "^3.0.5",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "heroku-ssl-redirect": "^0.0.4",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mobx": "^5.15.2",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.5",
    "mongodb-uri": "^0.9.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.7",
    "morgan": "1.9.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "on-build-webpack": "^0.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-session": "^1.0.2",
    "query-string": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-aria-menubutton": "^6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.11.2",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-share": "^4.0.1",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
    "react-stars": "^2.2.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "react-transition-group-plus": "^0.5.3",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "roman-numerals": "^0.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.5.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "striptags": "^3.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "superagent": "^5.2.1",
    "svg-text-wrap": "^0.0.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.7.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.2",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.4.20",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.18",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.6.0",
    "serviceworker-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.6.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea where to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Can you share `package.json` as well?

Comment: @funnydman I added it to the original question above.

Comment: Were you able to find out why the HMR interrupt error was thrown, @Lazerbrains?